# Summarise data by using index i

Tags: python, python-2.7

Codes:

```
for i, words in enumerate(list):
    syn = eachscore(num)
    for score in syn:
        count = count + 1
        sscore = str(score).split()
        first = sscore[2]
        second = sscore[4]
        sumf = float(sumf) + float(first)
        sums = float(sumd) + float(second)
    print i, words, sumf, sums
```

Results show:

```
0   A1  10  0
0   B1  2   27
1   B3  0   7
0   C1  1   10
1   C2  5   5
0   D1  10  1
1   D2  31  20
2   D5  20  10
```

I am trying to group the data.

Could someone suggest the way to sum the data by using index 'i' ? Please ...

Expect results:

```
A1  10  0
B1 B3   2   34
C1 C2   6   15
D1 D2 D5    61  31
```

Comment: How could your output be correct? `i`  is increased by 1 for each iteration, so that column should read `0, 1, 2, ..., len(list)-1`

Comment: Do you mean `print count, words, sumf, sums` instead of ` print i, words, sumf, sums`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?  I haven't tested it at all, but I believe it should be close.

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-2.7/bin/python

def subresult():
    for i, words in enumerate(list):
        syn = eachscore(num)
        for score in syn:
            count = count + 1
            sscore = str(score).split()
            first = sscore[2]
            second = sscore[4]
            sumf = float(sumf) + float(first)
            sums = float(sumd) + float(second)
        # changed your print to a yield
        yield (words, sumf, sums)

def process():
    # untested
    dict_ = {}
    for words, sumf, sums in subresult():
        if words in dict_:
            dict_[words][0] += sumf
            dict_[words][1] += sums
        else:
            dict_[words] = [ sumf, sums ]
    return dict_

def main():
    dict_ = process():
    for key, value in dict_.items():
        print key, value
```

Comment: It printed the same results as I got at the above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try this. Since you didn't include any example input, or the `eachscore()` method, I can't verify that this works. Additionally, the output you have posted in your question can't originate from the code example you provided, so I made some guesses.

```
import re
results = dict()

for words in list:
    syn = eachscore(num)

    # Results should be sorted by letters, e.g  get 'A' from the string 'A01'.
    # If this letter is case-insensitive, add .lower() to the expression
    key = re.sub('[0-9]*', '', words)

    # Try to append <words> to the dictonary item with key <key>.
    # If this fails, add a new entry (e.g. this is the first occurence of the letter)    
    try:
        results[key]['keys'].append(words)
    except KeyError:
        results[key] = {'keys': [words], 'sumf': 0, 'sums': 0}

    for score in syn:
        sscore = str(score).split()
        results[key]['sumf'] += float(sscore[2])
        results[key]['sums'] += float(sscore[4])

print results.items()
```

Comment: When I say working example, I mean you should provide code and input data such that we can __run__ the code, and get the output you provided in your question. This means that you need to provide us with sample `list`, and a working version of the function `eachscore`.

Comment: I got error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: No error but weird output. Output: A1 A1  10  0
B3 B3 B3 B3 B3 B3 0 7
B1 2 27
C2  C2  C2  C2  C2  C2  5 5 ...

Comment: The results still the same but print out as list.

Comment: Thanks for your time. the problem is not at eachscore. I just cannot find out the way to combine by using index i.

Comment: Next time you post a question here, you should think about how other users could help you. If we cannot test the code that we write, it may be very hard to give you any kind of help. Please, read the definition of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).